# Angular 8 - How to setup proxy to be able to serve locally an application that uses a web api with windows authentication?

Tags: angular, rest, .net-core, proxy, angular8

I'm using a REST .NetCore Web Api with my Angular 8 application.

The web api uses windows authentication and it was is own url (lets say http://api.mysite.com)

Whenever I run locally the application with

> ng serve

it tries to call the web api to authenticate and I get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

When I deploy my application and run it from let's say http://my-app.com it all works fine.

Should I setup an proxy to solve this? Any idea how?

Thanks

Comment: Check [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) and [this post](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/#configuring-your-angular-cli-dev-server-proxy).